# Usar Super Globais é obsoleto e inseguro?

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber se Usar Super Globais é obsoleto e inseguro no PHP, e o porquê dessa afirmação.

Pois agora temos o `filter_input` e fiquei com essa dúvida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não, usar [superglobais](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) não é obsoleto nem inseguro. O que é obsoleto e inseguro é ligar a [diretiva `register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals), que cria variáveis globais com base nas superglobais. Por exemplo, `$_POST['bla']` também existe como `$bla`.

Agora, os dados que existem nessas variáveis muitas vezes são (1) sensíveis – pode ser melhor evitar armazenar – ou (2) maliciosos – e aí entra o `filter_input`, entre outras medidas, para garantir que os dados de entrada sejam seguros. O que você tem nas superglobais são os dados de entrada "puros", cabe à sua aplicação tratá-los de maneira segura.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!